# WebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest, get only the main url

Tags: objective-c, webview, uiwebview

I have this code who get the url which is being opened by WebView:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

NSlog(@"My Url -> %@",request.URL);

}
```

this code sends me the complete url such as:

> https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl

In my case I just wanted to try to get the main url of this page, returning:

> www.google.com

How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.URL.host` should do the trick. For more info see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/host.